# Cleaning scanf buffer

Tags: c++, scanf

I'm trying to read a input in the following format

```
XgYsKsC XgYsKsC
```

Where X, Y, K are double values and C is a char.

I'm using the following code

```
scanf("%lf%*c%lf%*c%lf%*c", &L1g, &L1m, &L1s);
scanf(" %c", &L1c);

scanf("%lf%*c%lf%*c%lf%*c", &L2g, &L2m, &L2s);
scanf(" %c", &L2c);

double lat = (L1g * 3600 + L1m * 60 + L1s) / 3600.0;
double len = (L2g * 3600 + L2m * 60 + L2s) / 3600.0;

cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << lat << " " << len << endl;
```

It works fine on first iteration, but on the second one, it executes cout 2 times with wrong values.

So, I've add this 2 lines of code after the two scanf

```
cout << L1g << " " << L1m << " " << L1s << " " << L1c << endl;
cout << L2g << " " << L2m << " " << L2s << " " << L2c << endl;
```

With the following input:

```
23g27m07sS 47g27m06sW
23g31m25sS 47g08m39sW
```

I've got the following output:

```
23 27 7 S
47 27 6 W
23.45 47.45 // all fine until here
23.00 27.00 7.00 g // It should be printed 23 31 25 S
31.00 25.00 6.00 S // It should be printed 47 8 39 W
23.45 31.45 // Wrong Answer
23.00 27.00 7.00 g // And it repeats without reading inputs
8.00 39.00 6.00 W
23.45 8.65
```

I've tried several ways to fix that, but none worked. What am I missing?

Comment: Always check return value of `scanf`, for starters.

Comment: If you're programming in C++ why are you using `scanf`? If you want to handle errors in the input then I suggest you [read the whole line](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), put it into [an input string stream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and then use the normal "input" operator `>>` to attempt to parse the line. If you insist on using `scanf` then please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: Scanf is more fast than cin, it really counts on programming contests

Comment: In the first input, scanf returns 3, 1, 3, 1 and it's correct. On second input it returns 0, 1, 2, 1 and it should be 3, 1, 3, 1

Comment: "it repeats without reading inputs" effectively means, `scanf` failed at parsing, and left the input into the input buffer. And it will keep failing and leaving the input there, if you repeat trying to read it with non-matching format. This is why you need to check the `scanf` return values always, so you catch these parse errors.

Comment: In my not humble opinion, if you try to do competitive programming without knowing *very well* how to use functions like `scanf` and do error checking, you're not going to learn anything from it. Learn how to program well and how to make good, well documented and *working* programs first. *Then* you can go look into competitive programming. Don't do it to learn how to program, then all you will learn is to do (bad) competitive programming (badly) and nothing else.

Comment: [Not reproducible](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7648ef8180705af7), voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My standard pattern for this form of problem is ...

```
while( fgets( buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin ) != NULL ) { /* for each line */
     if( sscanf( buffer, "%lf%*c%lf%*c%lf%*c", &L1g, &L1m, &L1s) == 3 ) {
        /* handle input which met first criteria.
     } /* else - try other formats */
}
```

in your case, it may be easier to bind the 2 sets of input into one....

```
while( fgets( buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin ) != NULL ) { /* for each line */
     if( sscanf( buffer, "%lf%*c%lf%*c%lf%*c %lf%*c%lf%*c%lf%*c", &L1g, &L1m, &L1s, &L2g, &L2m, &L2s)) == 6 ) {
        /* handle input which met first criteria.
     } /* else - try other formats */
}
```

By separating the lines, you are limiting the disconnect between the data and the parse state.  If [s]scanf gets stuck, it can leave unexpected characters in the input stream, confusing subsequent attempts to read.

By reading a whole line, that limits the disconnect to a single line.  By reading all of a line in one scanf, it is either matching or not.